# Does a Combat Medic's Evasion Work Exactly as a Monk's Evasion?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, prestige-class

[Evasion](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/monk.htm#monkEvasion) granted by the [Combat Medic](http://www.realmshelps.net/charbuild/classes/prestige/general/combatmedic.shtml) prestige class states:

> Evasion (Ex): Beginning at 4th level, you can avoid damage from certain attacks with a successful Reflex save. See the [monk](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/monk.htm) class feature, page 41 of the Player's Handbook.

Does that mean the Evasion granted works in the same way as a monk (light armor or no armor) or does it simply mean to refer to the monk to see how evasion works (and therefore allowing whatever armor you are proficient with and wearing)?

Comment: Interesting, I just realized the Combat Medic did not even had specific armor/weapon proficiencies listed... At this level I would expect everyone running in Light Armor (with Mithral, it's easy enough), so even if restricted it might not be too problematic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's common to refer to abilities in other classes' descriptions. For instance, evasion of a **Scout** is defined by reference to the monk class too (*Complete Adventurer*, p. 13). Most Scout abilities require light or no armor.

I'd say that *wearing light or no armor* **is part of the definition** and it applies. Why reference at all if you don't want the full definition to apply?

Especially that it's the same for a **Rogue** (light or no armor) or for several random classes I looked at - if evasion is not defined by reference, it includes the same restriction (see **Halfling Outrider** (p. 39) or **Master Thrower** (p. 59) in *Complete Warrior*).

Also, **Divine Oracle** (p. 36, *Complete Divine*) has *Prescient Sense*, which is similar to evasion and includes the following:

> This form of evasion works no matter what armor the divine oracle wears, unlike the evasion ability used by monks and rogues.

Comment: I looked at a lot of classes, too, and got similar results. What surprised me, however, was how many classes grant a version of evasion that allows evasion to be used even while  the user's helpless (e.g. shadow scout, fleet runner, initiate of draconic mysteries). I know Reflex saving throws are supposed to be, sometimes, dumb luck, but, wow, that's weird.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Interesting, though I'd rule these are just mistakes. Was evasion any different in 3.0 for Rogues and Monks?

Comment: The special abilities are identical to each other in *3E*, but the *can't be used while helpless* language is new to *3.5*.

Comment: That's what I thought. Shadow scout is 3.0 (and this addition to evasion is missing in the errata, I guess), Initiate of Draconic Mysteries is borderline (only a few months after 3.5 was published). More difficult to assess Fleet Runner.

Answer (score 6):

## The combat medic's evasion works exactly like the [monk](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/monk.htm)'s [evasion](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/monk.htm#monkEvasion)

Were the combat medic's evasion to work *differently* from the monk's evasion, the combat medic's evasion description would say so. Instead, the combat medic's evasion description is almost entirely a redirect to the monk's evasion in the *Player's Handbook*. *Without* that redirection, the combat medic's evasion looks like this:

> Beginning at 4th level, you can avoid damage from certain attacks with a successful Reflex save.

...And, well, that's pretty much true of *everybody*, no matter what kind of (or if) armor's worn. Thus, to know what the combat medic's evasion even *does*, one *must* refer to the monk's evasion, and, because of *that*, the combat medic is limited to using evasion, like a monk, *only* while wearing light or no armor. (If a combat medic wants to wear medium or heavy armor and use evasion, [consensus says](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?65314-Ring-of-Evasion) to acquire a [*ring of evasion*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/rings.htm#evasion).)

That said, a combat medic's taken the feats Combat Casting and Dodge, and he's losing 1 hp per level compared to his cleric levels. A house rule allowing a combat medic to use evasion while in medium or heavy armor is unlikely to unbalance the game.